# Replace the whole line in the text document with the word at the end of the line

Tags: java

I am trying to replace the line with the word at the end of the line. Standing with the current I am getting the same line.

**Simple:**

```
apple - water- wall - street- light- book
```

**REsult should be**

```
book
```

**Code:**

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.contains("-") ) {                   
        String[] lineSplitted = line.split("-");
        int index = lineSplitted.length - 1;
        String direction = lineSplitted[index];
        line.replace(line, direction);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you give some example of what output you'd be expecting?

Comment: Why not just do `line = direction` ?  I'm assuming you have code omitted after the if block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to accomplish is an input line which is replaced with the last word in that line, you could simply change your code to the following:

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 String line = scanner.nextLine();
 String[] parts = line.split("\\s");
 line = parts[parts.length-1];`

Answer (score 0):

The type `String` is immutable, meaning that once constructed, the object itself cannot be changed. Instead of trying to update the string itself, update the reference (`line=direction;`).